# How can I split <?php the_content();?> in two different parts on same page

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to achieve the following below:

[Click here to see a diagram of what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LN5M.jpg)

1. Pull first content using the code in figure 1.
2. Have some sort of slideshow/gallery system.
3. Pull the remaining content using the code in figure 2.

Currently I just get duplicate content, I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: You can use substr. Open answers so that I can show you the working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It is wrong. You can use `<?php the_content();?>`only once in one page. If you want to show different content, put that content in widget and call the widget in page.

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar('id-of-widget-goes-here'); ?>
```

for example :-- `<?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar'); ?>`